# Pentagon Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math

In a regular pentagon ABCDE, point M is the midpoint of side AE, and segments AC and BM intersect at point Z. If ZA = 3, what is the value of AB? (The answer is supposed to be in simplest radical form.)

I think you're supposed to use similarities and I do realise that CA is equal to BE which I thought might help me but didn't, really.

Answer (score 0):

let $\angle ABM = \alpha, EBM = 36^\circ - \alpha.$ using the rule of sine on $\Delta ABM, \Delta EBM,$ we have $$ \frac{\sin(36^\circ - \alpha)}{\sin \alpha} = \frac 1 \tau \text{ where $\tau = \frac{1+\sqrt 5}2$ is the golden ratio.}\tag 1$$

using the rule of sine on $\Delta ABZ, $ we have $$\frac 3{\sin \alpha} = \frac{AB}{\sin (36^\circ+\alpha)} \tag 2$$

from $(1)$ and $(2),$ you can get the length of the side of the regular pentagon.